# Что такое Generator Objects в Python?

Tags: python, документация

Читаю документацию к Python 3.11.2 и нашёл вот такие [пункты про Generator Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/gen.html). Я примерно понимаю, как работают итераторы и что такое генераторы, но с таким определением сталкиваюсь впервые.

Перевод страницы тоже подробностей особо не внёс:

> Объекты-генераторы — это то, что Python использует для реализации
> итераторов-генераторов. Обычно они создаются путем повторения функции,
> которая возвращает значения, а не явным вызовом PyGen_New()или
> PyGen_NewWithQualName().

Проблема в том, что кода (примеров) там вообще нет, поэтому много неясности. Что это такое и для чего нужно?

Comment: Выражения вида `(x for x in чтототам)` или функции с yield'ом создают generator object'ы

Comment: [Если в документации забить в поиске слово generator](https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=generator), то первым в желтой рамочке выйдет выдержка из глоссария (словаря понятий) со [ссылкой](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), там в первую очередь и нужно смотреть, а не в C API.

Comment: Большое спасибо